# secure river stones in our driveway

Tags: driveway, stone

This is one of those "it looked good on paper, but not in practice" stories...

We have river stones in between concrete pads leading to our garage.  They're pretty, but the stones migrate for a few reasons:

- The driveway is on a slight incline.  Stones like to roll downhill.
- It's pure sand between the concrete pads, so there's nothing substantial to hold the stones in place.
- If the car tires don't stay exactly on the concrete pads (and they don't), they push the stones around.

So the question is: how would you anchor the stones in place so they don't continually migrate?  They don't have to be absolutely rigidly held in place -- maybe something semi-elastic would be ideal.

Here's a picture of what the stones should look like:
[image]
And here's a picture of how the stones end up:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would start by adding more stones to that sand only area. This will create even pressure across all of the stones when you drive over them. Those stones really should be set in concrete.